# What Is A Simple Way To Fix These Booleans?

Tags: java, boolean, logic

```
boolean a = true    
boolean b = true

<random code in here, booleans may or may not change>

if ((!a || !b) || (!a && !b)){
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

This code is not working for me, what is a simple solution to this problem?

To be clear:
The if statement should work:
**if at least one of the booleans is false**

3 cases:

```
a = False b = True
a = True b = False
a = False b = False
```

I could do this in one long if statement, but I was just wondering if there was a simple way to implement this.

Comment: are you setting the booleans to false at all? because it is checking if they are false and it looks like you have them set to true?

Comment: @JoseSwagKid : do you mean if either is false call doSomething() , else call doSomethingElse() ??????

Comment: Keeping it simple: if at least one of the booleans is false (so either one of them or both of them) - doSomethingElse should be called - I hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: since all of the answers are either `(!a || !b)` or `!(a && b)`, this seems like an apropos time to link to [DeMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to explain why these two statements are equivalent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
if( !a || !b ) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(!(a && b)) {  
  ....Then do something 
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The if statement should work: if at least one of the booleans is false

Comment: yes it does work.  if one of the booleans is false, then (a && b) will be false.  negating that makes it true.  therefore the if statement checks if at least one of the booleans is false

Comment: Sorry, I found another bug in my code, which was causing this code to not work. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

(Way too much time, breakdown of logic)

Start by applying [De Morgan's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to get the `!` outside: (Although other boolean algebra could be applied at this stage to skip a few steps, I like to show this.)

That is, given:

1. `(!a || !b)` (by DM) -> `!(a && b)` and
2. `(!a && !b)` (by DM) -> `!(a || b)`.

Then `(!a || !b) || (!a && !b)` (by substituion) -> `!(a && b) || !(a || b)`.

Applying DM again:

```
!( (a && b) && (a || b) )
```

Now using ["distributivity of ^ over v"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28logic%29#Laws) (`x = a && b; y = a; z = b`):

```
!( ((a && b) && a) || ((a && b) && b) )
```

And by "associativity" and "communicativity":

```
!( (a && a && b) || (a && b && b) )
```

And by "idempotence":

```
!( (a && b) || (a && b) )
!( (a && b) )
```

Simplified:

```
!(a && b)
```

Back by DM:

```
!a || !b
```

Of course, a simple [Truth Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) may have been easier to show this ..

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement will work just change your if Statement to this:

**if (!a || !b) {
}
As you can see above it will work when any one of the boolean is false .**

*All the Best.*

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution can be simplified to...

```
if (!a || !b) { .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

By checking whether one is false or both are false, you're making sure that both are true, or `a && b`. The opposite of `a && b` is `!a || !b`:

```
if (!a || !b) {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!(a && b)) {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```